# Synchronizing multiple StackBarchart (Highcharts) on a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, highcharts

I have multiple stack bar Chart on a page, which could have different series. If I hover over a stack in chart, I want this hover to be synced on other charts as well (showing the tooltip at the hovered name of stack, showing hover effect).

The problem is in the below example, the tooltip always shows the opposite stack series name.
For my case if I hover over installation in first stack bar chart it is showing tooltip for installation in first chart but in second chart it is showing tooltip for others.

How I can make sure if I hover over installation in first chart then tooltip of installation for that particular stack in second chart should be displayed.

Attached JSFiddle for same in the comments

Thanks

Comment: JsFiddle: <https://jsfiddle.net/zdm9xaqj/>

Comment: Hi, It's look like bug I need to chreck it [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnj3res6/5/).

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Is there any way I can get some temporary fix and proceed with it? It will be a great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It always reaches the second (last series) and in it changes the state to hover. To fix this you need to check if the series of the point we have the hover on compare with the series of the point we are checking in the loops.

```
function sharedMouseOver() {
  let currentX = this.x;
  let currentSeries = this.series.index;

  charts = Highcharts.charts;
  charts.forEach(function(chart, index) {
    chart.series.forEach(function(series, seriesIndex) {
      series.points.forEach(function(point, pointsIndex) {

        if (point.x == currentX && point.series.index == currentSeries) {
          chart.tooltip.refresh(point)
          point.series.setState('hover');
        }
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kfL5087x/1/